# Magento 2 : why module-checkout overrides country order?

Tags: magento2, checkout, vendor

I just wasted 3 hours trying to figure out why I couldn't seem to manipulate the order of the country_id field in the checkout shipping address only to find out that any value I insert in the `customer_eav_attribute` table is overridden by the magento CE code in the `vendor/magento/module-checkout` package.
 Why?!?!
What's the point of having sort order if the core code is going to override the value in the source code?
**vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml**

```
 <item name="country_id" xsi:type="array">
       <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">115</item>
   </item>
```

Comment: which version of magento are you using? Please post this as a issue/bug in github if you see this as a problem.

Comment: It's v2.2.2 and it's in the checkout module itself from the composer download! It was put there intentionally by someone.